# python 2.7 split confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I'm trying to write a function which takes a list as parameter, and remove new line '\n' character from each of the member of input list

Approach 1:

```
def remove_newline_list (lst):
        for i in (range(len(lst))):
                lst[i] = lst[i].split()[0]
print lst
```

prints:

***['orcl', 'orcl112']***

Approach 2:

```
def remove_newline_list (lst):
        for i in (range(len(lst))):
                lst[i] = lst[i].split('\n')[0]

print lst
```

prints:

***['o', 'r', 'c', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'c', 'l', '1', '1', '2']***

Can somebody explain me how can I explicitly split text at '\n' using 2nd approach

i.e. I want to explicitly specify the '\n' char as delimiter so that it doesn't split at other white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Just make yourself a new list:

```
lst = ['a\n', 'b', 'c\n']
new_lst = [item.rstrip() for item in lst]
```

Or - using `map`:

```
new_lst = list(map(str.rstrip, lst))
```

Both will yield

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you please explain me why Python behaves the way it does in Approach#2

Answer (score 0):

## This will work

You can goes through eanch element and strip the end character, in this case new line (`\n`) and assign back to that index.

```
lst = ['a\n', 'b', 'c\n']

for index, char in enumerate(lst):
  lst[index] = char.strip('\n')
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you please explain me why Python behaves the way it does in Approach#2

Comment: Approach #2 is working fine for me. Would you like to share the input you are passing to function in second approach ?

Comment: Apologize for replying late, Muhammad Usman Bashir. The list contains Oracle SID values i.e. orcl, orcl112

Comment: @JK As i mentioned earlier second code working fine for me. There must me some issue. while sending input to function. you must check the way you are passing input to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_newline_list (lst):

  temp_list = []

  for item in lst:
    temp_list.append(item.strip('\n'))

  return temp_list



mylist = [ 'jane\n' , 'doe\n' , 'richard\n' , 'stallman\n']

print(mylist)

print(remove_newline_list(mylist))



['jane\n', 'doe\n', 'richard\n', 'stallman\n']
['jane', 'doe', 'richard', 'stallman']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you please explain me why Python behaves the way it does in Approach#2